# Calling an array of a different function that belongs to the same javascript class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

Hi guys I'm a newbie in JS and I'd like to know how to call an array of a different class inside another function that belongs to the same javascript class.
Here is the sample code:

```
class Something {

  constructor () {}

  async functionA () {
       this.list = []
  }

  async functionB () {
       console.log(this.list)
  }

}
```

Comment: You cannot call an array, you can only call a function. And what do you mean by "different class", there is only one in the code you've shown?

Comment: So `var thing = new Something(); thing.functionA(); thing.functionB();`? That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor you can declare your variables with `this.variableName` and then other class methods will be able to get and set the value. You can also access it from an instance of the class.

```
class Something {

    constructor() {
        this.list = []
    }

    async functionA () {
        this.list = [ 'foo', 'bar']
    }

    async functionB () {
        console.log(this.list)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing seems to work fine...

```js
class Something {
  constructor () {}

  async functionA () {
    this.list = ['ok']
  }

  async functionB () {
    console.log(this.list)
  }
}

const a = new Something();
a.functionA();
a.functionB();
```

https://codepen.io/benaloney/pen/dyPpELK